# In Canada, do employees have the right to not be listed publicly?

Tags: canada, employment, privacy

Let's say Microsoft Canada decided to put online their employee directory (name, title, phone number, work address), indexed by Google.

Let's say one employee does not want people to find out where he works for some reasons.

If requested, is it mandatory for Microsoft to remove the employee profile?

To make it more complex, what if the employee no longer works there?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer : Contact information is not covered by PIPEDA.

In other words, it's not considerate personal information.

In my example, Microsoft would NOT have to delete the information, unless the employee left.

https://www.priv.gc.ca/en/privacy-topics/privacy-laws-in-canada/the-personal-information-protection-and-electronic-documents-act-pipeda/pipeda-compliance-help/guide_org/

See section "What is not covered"

Comment: I'm confused. Where does it say "it's not considered personal information" You should quote content from your link instead.